# The "paragraph" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, paragraph

On Drupal 8.8.8 with paragraphs:^1.12, getting this error:

```
The "paragraph" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition()
```

Same error with other versions of paragraphs.

Comment: Is your database up to date?
Try to run drush updatedb.

Comment: @RadosławHalicki I tried that but still get the error. I also tried drupal updb which throws the same error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you installed Drush, you can use the following command to delete the configuration object from the database.

```
drush cdel core.entity_view_mode.paragraph.preview
```